# Mass update with Visualforce button on listview

Tags: visualforce, list-view

Novice developer here, trying to adapt [Trailhead code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration/javascript_button_alternatives) to a somewhat similar use for class attendance. I want the following to happen —

1. user clicks multiple boxes on a list view of enrollees
2. user then clicks a Visualforce button ("Mark Present") to update the Attended checkbox on each record (also shown on the listview)
3. the listview then shows all the checked boxes with minimal obvious refreshing, and definitely no new page returning

Here's the listview (with the button that isn't functioning properly) —
[image: listview with button in place]

And here's my code, which isn't working as I'd like —

[image: problematic code]

Any guidance on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: read page 59-61 in [Visualforce in Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) for how to do mass updates.  This PDF is an oft-forgotten but really good reference on VF

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a great resource. I'll study those pages.